# Pointer syntax confusion (*ptr vs ptr)

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I've been spending a couple days trying to understand pointers but the syntax still confuses me.

When you write say, `int *ptr;`, what is the difference between `ptr` and `*ptr` after this declaration?

In K&R they begin the chapter on pointers with this example:

```
int x = 1, y = 2, z[10];
int *ip; /* ip is a pointer to int */
ip = &x; /* ip now points to x */
y = *ip; /* y is now 1 */
*ip = 0; /* x is now 0 */
ip = &z[0]; /* ip now points to z[0] */
```

This made me think `*ip` was used for integer values (since `*ip` was declared an int) while plain `ip` was used for addresses, and `ip` (`&x`) would "point to" `*ip` (`x`). In other words, the address of x would point to x.

But then comes an example that throws that idea under the bus.

```
swap(&a,&b);

void swap(int *px, int *py) /* interchange *px and *py */
{
    int temp;
    temp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;
}
```

Based on the function assignment, it's clear `*px = &a` and `*py = &b`, which effectively defeats my idea that only `px` and `py` can store addresses, not `*px` and `*py`. That leaves me very confused about the relationship between `px` & `*px` and `py` & `*py`.

I did some experimenting after this:

```
int x = 4;
int y = &x;
printf("%d %p \n",y,&y);
```

...and noticed this actually compiles correctly, although the values of `y` and `&y` differ slightly when converting from hex to dec and vice versa.

This leaves me more confused than ever, and it's apparent there's some fundamental concept about pointers I'm just not grasping, no matter how much time and energy I dedicate towards it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This made me think `*ip` was used for integer values (since `*ip` was declared an `int`) while plain `ip` was used for addresses, and `ip` (`&x`) would "point to" `*ip` (`x`). In other words, the address of x would point to x.

**That's right. Exactly.**

(Well, almost. It's not that `*ip` was declared as `int`, but `ip` was declared as `int *`. That's what confused you, see the next part.)

> Based on the function assignment, it's clear `*px = &a` and `*py = &b`

No, not at all.

`px` and `py` are pointers themselves. `px = &a` and `py = &b`, and initially `*px = a` and `*py = b` (of course after the swap, this changes).

What presumably confused you in the second case is that the `*` character has two meanings in the context of pointers.

The one is, when you **declare** a variable of pointer type, the `*` character acts as the **pointer qualifier,** i. e. `T *p` indicates that the variable `p` is a pointer to type `T`.

The other meaning is the `*` **operator**, which is not used in declarations but in expressions, where it **dereferences** the pointer, i. e. it accesses the value it points to.

Comment: @Amalgam54 Because it's not much more intuitive. In fact, it's misleading. `int* p1, p2;` visually suggests that `p1` and `p2` are of type `int *`, whereas the pointer qualifier applies to **variables** and not **types,** so only `p1` is an `int *`, and `p2` is a plain `int`. That's why `int *p1, p2;` (and occasionally, `int *p1, *p2;`) is conceptually more correct.

Comment: Had to read your explanation a few times but it makes sense now. Thanks for all the help, it's immensely appreciated!