# C Pointers: *ptr vs &ptr vs ptr

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose `*ptr` points to a variable.  What does `*ptr`, `&ptr`, and `ptr` each mean?

Many times, I get confused between them.  Do anyone mind clarifying between those statements and give some concrete examples?

Comment: `ptr` is the same across all three; it's a variable. Two of those have operators that do work on that variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer syntax confusion (\*ptr vs ptr)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130513/pointer-syntax-confusion-ptr-vs-ptr)

Comment: I don't consider as a duplication @Leushenko

Comment: You could check [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for better explanation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take the following variables in a function.

```
int i = 0;
int* ptr = &i;
```

In the function, the memory layout could look something like:

Memory corresponding to `i`:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|       0       |
+---+---+---+---+
^
|
Address of i
```

Memory corresponding to `ptr`:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| address of i  |
+---+---+---+---+
^
|
Address of ptr
```

In the above scenario,

```
*ptr == i == 0
ptr == address of i == address of memory location where the vale of i is stored
&ptr == address of ptr == address of memory location where the value of ptr is stored.
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a computer memory:

[image]

```
int i = 1023
```

---

If I want to print `i`, then I just have to do:

```
printf(..., i);
// out: 1023
```

If I want to print where `i` lives, then I just have to do:

```
printf(..., &i);
// out: 0x4
```

---

But let's say I want to remember where `i` lives:

```
int *i_ptr = &i; // i_ptr is a variable of type int *
```

Then I can print it this way:

```
printf(..., i_ptr); 
// out: 0x04
```

---

But if just print out the value of `i`, I need a `*`:

```
printf(..., *i_ptr); // * also doubles as a way to follow the pointer
// out: 1023
```

---

Or I can just print out where `i_ptr` lives:

```
printf(..., &i_ptr);
// out: 0x32
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the declarations

```
int i = 0x01234567;
int *ptr = &i;
```

the following are true:

```
Expression         Type          Value
----------         ----          -----
       ptr         int *         Address of i
      *ptr         int           Value stored in i (0x01234567)
      &ptr         int **        Address of ptr variable
```

In memory, it would look something like the following (assuming 32-bit `int`)

```
Item       Address       0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
----       -------       ---- ---- ---- ----
   i       0x7fffbb00    0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67
 ptr       0x7fffbb04    0x7f 0xff 0xbb 0x00
```

So the value of `ptr` is `0x7fffbb00`, the value of `&ptr` is `0x7fffbb04`, and the value of `*ptr` is `0x01234567`.

Answer (score 1):

If `*ptr` points to a variable, then that would mean that `*ptr` is a pointer itself. That would mean you're declaring `ptr` as follows: `int **ptr;`

In this case:

- `ptr` is a pointer to the pointer to your variable
- `*ptr` is the pointer to your variable
- `&ptr` gives you the address of ptr, so a pointer to the pointer to the pointer to your variable

For example:

```
//set up work
int x;
int *intermediatePtr;
int **ptr;
x = 5;
intermediatePtr = &x; //used only for additional level of indirection in this example
ptr = &intermediatePtr; //ie *ptr = &x;

//should print out the memory address for the pointer to the address of x
printf("%d", ptr);
//should print out the memory address of x (different memory location than above)
printf("%d", *ptr);
//should print out the memory address of the variable 
//which holds the memory address of x 
//(again, different memory location than both above examples)
printf("%d", &ptr);
```

If `ptr` points to a variable instead of `*ptr` (ie `int *ptr; ptr = &x;`), there is one less level of indirection than my above example.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have:

```
int number = 5;
int *ptr = &number;
```

- ptr will be the variable, of type int *, instead storing a 5 or
  "foo", it will store an address like 0xf0f0f004 or whatever it is the
  address of the variable number.
- *ptr will be the value of what it is in this address of memory 0xf0f0f004, in this specific case is 5.
- &ptr will be the address where it is located the variable that will
  be in other place for example 0xff00ffaa or whatever.

ptr and number are located in different places in memory, both stores values, one just store a number and the other store an address. And the language allows you putting *, access the value of this address.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ptr; // declares a pointer to integer.
int val; // declares an integer.
&val; // pointer to val
ptr = &val; // ptr will now point to val
*ptr = 5; // same as writing val = 5
ptr++; // pointer to the next int after val (in this case, it will be undefined behaviour, it is useful if this pointer pointed to a cell in an array)
int arr[10]; // declares an array of size 10
ptr = arr; // ptr now points to arr[0] (name of an array can be implicity cast to pointer to first element)
ptr++; // ptr now points to arr[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `&` = Reference
- `*` = De reference
- ptr is the identifier/name. You declare it by `int *ptr`.

  Here is a small C program:

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
  int *ptr,ref;

  ptr= &ref;

  ref=12;

  printf("%d\n",*ptr );
  }
  ```

  - In C,`int *ptr` is an integer pointer. You can use other data types like float, char etc,.
  - `ptr = &ref` gets the address of `ref` and stores in `ptr`. Since we declared `ptr` as integer pointer, when we print the value pointed, we have to De-reference it by using `*`.