# Pointers addresses behaviour

Tags: c, pointers

For example:

```
int *ptr
```

What's the difference beetween the &ptr and ptr
because when i do

```
printf("ptr= %d  but &ptr=%d",ptr,&ptr);
```

the result is not the same.

Comment: What is the difference between `&x` and `x` (where `x` is *any* variable)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking why 1 is not 2

Comment: Here is additional information on the same question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/25044661/5135243

Comment: Just write `void *x; x = &x;` and you expectation is met. Btw, don't `printf()` pointers as integers.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` is the pointer value (it's an address).

`&ptr` is the address of the pointer object.

To print a pointer value you have to use:

```
printf("ptr= %p  but &ptr=%p", (void *) ptr, (void *) &ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
  {
          int *ptr;
          int i=5; 
          ptr=&i;
          printf("ptr= %p  but &ptr=%p",(void *)ptr,(void *)&ptr);
          return 0;
   }
```

Here in this code `ptr` will give address of `i` and `&ptr` will show address where value of `ptr` is stored. And to see values of `i` you can print `*ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ptr;
```

delcares a pointer variable (pointer means a variable which points to other memory location)

```
printf("ptr= %d  but &ptr=%d",ptr,&ptr);
```

printing ptr with %d gives the value of the varible ptr which will be a memory location,If the pointer is not initialized it will give some value which is insignificant

printing &ptr by %d gives the address of the pointer variable ptr which will be a memory location where the varible ptr is allocated